# Не переведён текст ошибки при удалении своего вопроса, на который дан ответ

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Не переведена фраза:

> You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and
>   effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center.

Когда пытаешься удалить свой вопрос, на который дан ответ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выполнил [перевод](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/135334332?q=key%3A01f66fe438548072a16f4f49a08c0f12):

> Вы не можете удалить этот вопрос, так как другие участники потратили время и усилия, отвечая на него. Для получения дополнительной информации обратитесь к $linkStart$справочному центру$linkEnd$.

Будет на сайте после обновления базы и пересборки движка.